# Is there a URI structure for launching Windows Store Apps from the browser?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

I can see that for Microsoft apps, I can launch them in IE with the format `app_name:///`, for example:

```
bingweather:///
bingmaps:///
xboxgames:///
```

I was wondering if this is possible to do in Chrome, but first wondered if it was possible to do with non-MS apps.

Can any app be launched from the web, or only certain ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my (limited) knowledge, yes you can. The app / software need to register those specific app_name to the OS and the OS can call up the correct App / Software.

Further information from Microsoft on how exactly to achieve that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

One example:
If you ever use BitTorrent (in my case uTorrent) they register magnet:// that if clicked will invoke the uTorrent client without the need of downloading the .torrent file as the magnet URI will already have all the information needed to start the torrent.

Edited to add:
(I just realized you wanted specifically for Windows Store Apps)

Then my answer is "not sure". The above seems to work for "any" app, so assuming the above is working, and you can find the program / executable for the windows app on the HDD somewhere, then yes it is possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I bet you're right that the app needs to register itself.