# Teach chrome [information]: links

Tags: google-chrome

There are many [information]: links. For example, `mailto:`.

I want to "teach" chrome how to interpret a `bitcoin:` address, by having it open up `blockchain.info/address/[stuff after bitcoin:]`

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/665059/is-there-a-uri-structure-for-launching-windows-store-apps-from-the-browser), and it seems to be the case that such links have to be registered system wide.

Here is an example for what you want according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- In `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` create a new key called `bitcoin` (or anything?).
- Modify the `(Default)` string to say `URL:bitcoin`.
- Make an empty string named `URL Protocol`.
- Make a new key in `bitcoin` called `DefaultIcon`. Modify `(default)` to point at Chrome's path. (I think this is optional. I also think you can point this at any program whose icon you want. I believe the `,1` in the docs means use the first icon available.)
- Make a new key in `bitcoin` called `shell`, and in shell a new key named `command`.
- Modify the `(Default)` string in `command` to point at Chrome's path with whatever flags neccessary to launch a URL. The "stuff after bitcoin:" will be in the variable `%1`. For example: 
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://blockchain.info/address/" "%1"`